# Application manifest file for Azure AD Proxy Applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to edit the application manifest file for an Azure AD Proxy Application but there is no option to download the file from the portal. Does anyone know if a Proxy Application even has a manifest? I would assume so. Is there an equivilent way in Powershell?

Comment: Have you read this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-application-proxy-enable/?

Comment: Yes. I have no issue setting up the proxy application but i need access to the application manifest for it so i can edit the knownClientApplications. Unless i am mistaken that article does not mention the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The official [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-application-manifest/) covers this pretty well including screenshots.

In the Azure AD portal you need to browse to the application, then on the application dashboard you should see the link at the bottom to download the manifest, just like you can see below.

[image: Azure AD Portal - Application Dashboard]